# How print an X constructed from the letter X and uses the underscore as a space in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

So heres the problem:
Write a program using TypeScript that prints an X constructed from the letter X and uses the underscore as a space. The size of the x is based on a variable n that will indicate the size of the letter to print (in a matrix of n x n). For example, for n: = 5 you get:

```
X___X_
_X_X_
__X__
_X_X_
X___X
```

and for n: = 6 we obtain:

```
X____X_
_X__X_
__XX__
__XX__
_X__X_
X____X
```

this is my code:

```
var n = 5;
var space = "";
for(var i = 2; i < n; i++){
    space = space + "_";
    for(var k = 1; k < i * 1; k++){
        space = space + "X";
    }
  console.log(space);
}
```

And the ouput is:

```
_X
_X_XX
_X_XX_XXX
```

Comment: Are there really supposed to be both lower-case and upper-case Xs? And `x___x_` has 6 characters, not 5 like all the other lines, what's the logic behind that?'

Comment: Sounds like you need a different approach. Why is `i` starting at `2`?

Comment: Tip: Use `let` in preference to `var`. Use `x += y` in preference to `x = x + y`.

Comment: Figure out how to draw a diagonal line, like `i == k` and then figure out how to flip that, like `i == (n - k)` and you can draw an X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the index of the outer loop is equal to the index of the inner loop, OR if the index of the outer loop is equal to (the index of the inner loop minus the line length) to decide on whether a square should have an X or not:

```js
const makeX = n => {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let line = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      line += i === j || j === (n - i - 1) ? 'X' : '_';
    }
    console.log(line);
  }
};
makeX(5);
console.log('');
makeX(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 5;
for(let i=0; i<x; i++) {
let str = "";
  for(let k=0; k<x; k++) {
    if(k==i || k==x-1-i) {
      str+='X'
    } 
    else {
      str+='_'
    }
    if(k==x-1) {
    console.log(str)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const X = n => new Array(n).fill(n).forEach(
  (_,j,a) => console.log(a.map(
    (_,i) => i == j || i == (n-j-1) ? 'X' : '_'
  ).join(''))
);
```